# Prefer iPhone when synchronizing playlists between iTunes and iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

When synchronizing Playlists between iTunes and an iPhone, by default, the playlists of iTunes are preferred - even if the iPhone's change is more current. I prefer to change my playlists on the go on my iPhone, so I want to change this behaviour. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of any settings that this will work with iTunes/iPhone out of the box. But you could give [iGadget X](http://www.ipodsoft.com/site/index.php?n=IGadget.HomePage) a try:

> ** iPad, iPod touch and iPhone Support **
>
> iGadget (Windows and Mac) now supports
>   the iPad, iPod touch and iPhone.
>   However, due to the limitation of the
>   Notes feature on these devices, only
>   the Music Transfer, Playlist Transfer
>   and Music Listing functions are
>   available when used with the iPad,
>   iPod touch or iPhone.

[image]

PS: It's shareware ($19.99)

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but I need full synch capabilities (especially Apps). Any way to use iTunes?